# Can a character array be used as expression for switch statement?

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
  char name[20];

  printf("\n enter Your Name: ");
  gets(name);

  switch(name)
  {
    default : printf( "Invalid" );
  }

  getch();
}
```

So my question: is a char array OR Simple array valid in expression for switch and, if it is valid, then what are the case values?

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 4):

The `switch` statement is using the address of the character array as the parameter. So no it won't work as you expect it to.

It follows the same reason why you can't throw strings into a switch and expect it to work. (and same with string comparisons)

Answer (score 4):

No, the standard says

> The controlling expression of a switch statement shall have integer
>   type.

in your case the address of the string would be taken which is not considered to be an integer in that respect.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. You will need to create an array of character arrays (strings). Search them to convert to and integer (index into that array) and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. To compare strings/char-arrays, you have to use some other functions such as 'strcmp'.
If you really want to use the switch-case structure, you can map each of your strings to distinct integers and switch by it. Here is a [DEMO](http://ideone.com/cz8se).

Answer (score 0):

If you ask about its validity, yes it's valid and the compiler would be happy to compile. However, the compiler won't compare the content (the characters in the string), instead the pointer value would be compared.

Comment: I don't really know about the standard, but at least Tiny C could compile it FYI

Comment: Well, then this is an extension of tc. I wonder how this is supposed to work for them, since by the standard the cases have to be constant expressions, too. `gcc` doesn't compile this code with a precise error message about the `switch` condition, and `clang` even happens to find other errors in the code.

Comment: gcc 4 has evolved a lot (compared to gcc 2 - 3) in terms of what should be regarded as error (and AFAIK some are finally included to the standard), clang is already strict(er) from the beginning. the cases are constant strings, which is a constant expression IMHO

Comment: If you don't know about the standard, you probably shouldn't give advice on what's valid and what isn't.  There's a lot of compiler extensions out there.